# What is the difference between 老X and X老 as a term of address?

Tags: usage, difference, terms-of-address

Here is an exchange I saw in a WeChat group today:

```
李xx： 请大家为28号投票！
A： 谢谢您，李老！ 【抱拳】【抱拳】
B： 谢谢您，老李！ 【偷笑】
A： “李老”是尊称，“老李”是称呼！
C： 【强】
```

I'm fairly familiar with the usage 老X as a term of address. And I gather that X老 is a much more respectful term. I guess my question is, when would I ever actually use X老? I seem to recall hearing a story a long time ago about a foreigner trying to use X老, but the old man being addressed was "too young" and the effect was awkward.

Related questions:

- ["小王" 和 "老王" how to determine which to use?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/78/%E5%B0%8F%E7%8E%8B-%E5%92%8C-%E8%80%81%E7%8E%8B-how-to-determine-which-to-use)
- [What is a good form of address for a male friend who is too old to be 小, too young to be 老, and too humble to be called 大?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/what-is-a-good-form-of-address-for-a-male-friend-who-is-too-old-to-be-%E5%B0%8F-too-you)
- [What is the polite/proper way to address elderly whom I am not familiar with?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/what-is-the-polite-proper-way-to-address-elderly-whom-i-am-not-familiar-with/13376#13376)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explanation: In the case of people with good moral standing and high reputation (德高望重), you can add 老 after their surname, this is a very respectful (很恭敬的) address.

Screenshot from a book on [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=PO1mAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT66&lpg=PT66&dq=%E5%A7%93%E5%90%8E%E8%80%81%E5%AD%97&source=bl&ots=rN69QBfLRW&sig=hu50pOR04eUt4GYZwltg6gHH18E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RuKHVYGvKsa07Qa0h5_wBA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%E5%A7%93%E5%90%8E%E8%80%81%E5%AD%97&f=false). The relevant, very short sentence touching your question is highlighted (sorry, not very professional, but legible).

[image]

Here's another [source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:svgao1Hc0TgJ:gz.eywedu.com/21cnjy/TS013024/0013_ts013024.htm&client=ubuntu&hl=en&gl=hu&strip=1&vwsrc=0) explaining this (mentioning scientists, statesmen, old teachers as the circle to whom you can apply this):

> 对德高望重的老科学家、老政治家、老教育家、老文学家，可以在姓之后加“老”字，以表示尊重。如“郭老”、“‘钱老”、“徐老”。

Answer (score 1):

- `X老` is used to show respect to old person who usually has a high social/academic status.
- `老X` is used like `Mr.X` as a prefix to given name, which shows closeness in an informal condition.